# Scope issue: required file cant access variables when called in class

Tags: php, class, object, require, scopes

```
$test = test;

class getFile{
    public function __construct($fileName){
    require $fileName;
  } 
}

$get = new getFile('file.php');
```

So file.php contains,    echo $test;

If I was to call this outside the class e.g

require 'test.php'; it would get $test fine
But calling inside the class has obvious scope issues. How can I give the files required within the function access the to variables?

EDIT: ------------------------

I have multiple variables I wish this file to access (they are all dynamic based on the page, so adding x & y variables is impossible as they won't always be set) Rather than declaring each variable as globally accesible, is there no way to allow the required file in the class, access theese variables as if it wasn't?

Thank you guys for the feedback. Unfortunatly what I want does not seem possible, but you have inspired me to create a workaround that registers the most important variables I need my files to access as global.

Comment: Add the variables to method scope

Answer (score 1):

```
public function __construct($fileName) {
    global $test;
    require $fileName;
}
```

will work

Comment: Perhpas i'm not clear enough, I have thousands of files I wish this file to access. E.g file: 1,2,3,4 + all their variables are set, and this file needs access to them- this methods is impracticall for something that large.

Comment: @BillyJakeO'Connor please check my second answer to this problem

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could declare a global variable within your class, like so:

```
$text = 'test';

class getFile {
   public function __construct($fileName) {
      global $test;
      require $fileName;
   }
}

$get = new getFile('file.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP variables declared in the global scope are not automatically made available inside functions or methods. You have to explicitly declare them to be globals:

```
file.php:

    <?php
    global $test
    echo $test
```

or

```
public function __construct($filename) {
    global $test;
    require $filename;
}
```

would both fix the problem. Even though the `file.php` script appears to be global, as there's no function definition within it, it's still bound to the scope of the `__construct()` method in your object, which will NOT have $test global.

Answer (score 0):

responding to your comment, i have workaround you may like

```
class getFile{
    public $files = Array();
    public function __construct($fileName){
        $this->files[] = $fileName;
    } 
}

$get = new getFile('file.php');

foreach($get->files as $file) require($file);
```

or maybe u can create static methods?

```
class getFile{
    public static $files = Array();
    public static function get($fileName){
        self::$files[] = $fileName;
    } 
}

getFile::get('file1.php');
getFile::get('file2.php');
getFile::get('file3.php');

foreach(getFile::$files as $file) require($file);
```

Comment: Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::registerShutdownFunc() should not be called statically :/ sorry buddy but it's not gunna work.